# Insert Excel row using format from row below, not above

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, add-on

I need to insert a row into an existing Excel worksheet using C# but keep the existing formatting.

The default behaviour in Excel is to use the formatting of the row above, which in some cases is what I don't want as this could be different.

I am sure I have seen that there is a way to specify using the format of the row below rather than from the row above but I can't find it now.

Does anyone know how to specify this?

This is the code I am using:

```
sheet.Range[string.Format("{0}:{0}", row)]
  .EntireRow
  .Insert(
  Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `CopyOrigin` parameter as well.

```
sheet.Range[string.Format("{0}:{0}", row)]
  .EntireRow
  .Insert(
  Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown,
  Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
)
```

See here for details on [Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.insert.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and [that enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlinsertformatorigin.aspx).

It is possible to get this parameter by recording a macro.  There is a small box that pops up when you insert the row to choose where the formatting comes from.

[image: format options]

Comment: Fantastic I'll give that a go! :)